# notepad ++ match pl sql start and finish of block

Tags: plsql, notepad++

Notepad++ can match ( ), { }.
I use it to edit pl sql code, and wonder if it is able to match beginning and end of a pl sql block

for example

```
if a=1 then
  null;
end if;
```

when I point to `then` I wish `end if` to be highlighted.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version has such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are talking about is called brace matching, and I suspect that it only is possible for the braces themselves.  Have you tried looking for plug-ins that do something like this?  Here is a link to a bunch of Notepad++ plugins. http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/